# YouTube live streaming API LiveChatMessages

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm trying to bring in the chats of a YouTube event through an Android app.

To my understanding, to bring a channel’s live chat on YouTube. I need to know the BroadcastId from the YouTube steaming API. Since I want to see how it works on a real live stream event I'm trying to bring in other people’s live stream chats.

But I'm having trouble calling a random live event’s chat to appear on my test base YouTube app.

So my question is, is there a way to call in the chats of a live stream event? Can you tell me how to know the BroadcastId or another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get chat information from the API from live events other than your own.  This is a restriction of the API.  If you want to test out the chat API, create an unlisted live event for testing and use the chat there.

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7OyvXCM63uQ&key=API_KEY&part=liveStreamingDetails,snippet
I came across this url it seems to work..is there a problem I would face in this process?

Comment: It currently IS possible to list liveChatMessages from other people's live events IF you know the `liveChatId` for the event.  However, I think you cannot obtain *this*  via the API for events not your own (it is normally found in the liveBroadcast resource).

Perhaps someone you know would give you one for one of their events, if you asked?

Hopefully this distinction will be useful for some people finding this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The active live chat ID is available in the liveStreamingDetails node of the video object associated with a live broadcast.